# Passing data from javascript to action method in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have placed a bootstrap toggle switch in my application
Now i want is to send the On and Off values to my action method

Bellow is my razor syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset style="height:60px">
    <legend style="text-align:center;  font-size:large; font-family:'Times New Roman'; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">Remote On/Off</legend>
    <input id="test_id" name="cmdName" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">

</fieldset>}
```

For passing data to controller from `JS` i have searched many articles and found that ajax is the way to do it

Bellow is my script for ajax inside JS

```
<script>
var cmdName = '@Session["cmdName"]';


    $("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: 'On',
                success: function () {
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: 'Off',
                success: function () {
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
        }
    }); </script>
```

I have also used session variable but getting null value in it

Bellow is my controller code

```
public ActionResult MultiGraph(string search, string start_date, string End_date, string cmdName, int? page)
{
//search contain serial number(s)
//cmdName is for input checkbox 
}
```

Bellow is the image for my switch button

[image]

When i switch it to **Off** then this Off string should be sent to my action method and vise versa

**Updated Code**

After reading comments i have done the following changes to my code

I have added a new action method of type `Post`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ToggleSwitch (string search, string cmdName)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var dtt = db.ADS_Device_Data.Select(a => a.Device_Serial_Number).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var item in dtt)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item, Value = item });
            }
        }

        ViewBag.search = items;

        return View();
    }
```

Bellow are changes in my razor

```
$("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ToggleSwitch")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: '{"cmdName": "On"}',
                success: function () {
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ToggleSwitch")',
                type: 'Post',
                data: '{"cmdName": "Off"}',
                success: function () {
                    alert(data)
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But still i get no alert message, when i inspect element i found this error

[image]

I am stuck to this problem from almost 2 days

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your Action takes 4 (or optionally 5) parameters, yet you're only passing a single string; either `On` or `Off`. And even then you're not providing a parameter name

Comment: actually i just want to pass the command name On or Off to my action method

Comment: Further to Rory's comment you also havent specified that you are posting to the server by decorating your action method with the correct attribute '[HTTPPOST]' I think by default its set to '[HTTPGET]'

Comment: @faisal1208 If you are posting to the server your parameters must match whats expected by the action method. Thats what Rory is trying to tell you.

Comment: @Kendo actually my current action method is 'HTTPPOST' and i can't change it because all of my 'GET' related work is done here

Comment: @Kendo have a look at my updated code

Comment: Have you compiled? Is your action method in `Home` Controller?

Comment: Yes i have compiled it and it's in my Home Controller

Comment: @anmarti my switch code is in a partial view and it's rendering in my layout and my multigraph action is also using this layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$` character to invoque `jQuery` functions and pass your data from page to controller with the same name you defined in the action method using `Json` notation:

```
        '{"cmdName": "On"}',

         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ToggleSwitch")',
            type: 'Post',
            data: '{"cmdName": "On"}',
            success: function () {
                alert(data)
            }
```

Furthermore, you might need to decorate your mvc action whith the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: I don't see the difference in his sample code and your solution.

Comment: @Uporabnik003 Look at data property.